# I know this code does not work, why does the code that I found does? What makes the wrong code, wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is from some exercise in some coding book. The goal is to use a for loop and jQuery to print your friends name on a different line; but every time I open it the page becomes unresponsive. I want to know exactly why in full detail.

This is the code that does not work:

```
var friendsName = prompt("enter a friends name");

for(friendsName; friendsName !== null;){
    $("body").append("<p>" + friendsName + "<p>");
}
```

this is the code that does:

```
for(var listYourFriends;listYourFriends !== null;listYourFriends = prompt("enter a friends name"))
{

   if(listYourFriends !== undefined){$("body").append("<p>" + listYourFriends + " smells" + "</p>");
    }


    else if( listYourFriends === null){
        break;
    }
}
```

but now that I got the answer I have no idea why this code works but the other does not. The other one, though it did set off some alarms for me, seemed to me like it should have made sense. can someone explain the differences between the two?

Comment: Where is the non-working code?

Comment: [for syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#Syntax). The last part of the `for` loop gets evaluated on each loop. If you leave it blank, it will get evaluated just "the first time", and that's why you end up with an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will go it to infinite loop because the condition **`friendsName !== null` for `for` loop never gets `false`**. For example when you enter some name into prompt it will not be changed again and will remain same throughout the code.

You need to update `friendsName` with new value in every loop.

```js
var friendsName = prompt("enter a friends name");

for(friendsName; friendsName !== null;){  
  $("body").append("<p>" + friendsName + "<p>");
  friendsName = prompt("enter a friends name");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Why code works?

According to MDN the syntax for the `for` statement is

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
```

Here `final-expression` is the part which will be evaluated during each iteration. In the above code we are executing the following line during each iteration.

```
friendsName = prompt("enter a friends name");
```

So we can put that at the place of `[final-expression]` and that will behave the same. So that's the reason the code given in question works.

Comment: should not repeat prompt in for loop, just put in for condition

Comment: @HienNguyen What do you mean by put in **for condition**?

Comment: this is better for(var listYourFriends;listYourFriends !== null;listYourFriends = prompt("enter a friends name"))

Comment: so basically the code that does not work will go into an infinite loop that prints the same name over and over again? Thank you, your answer has been very helpful

Comment: @HienNguyen Yes I know it is but the question is not about better code. The question is about understanding. In the OP's try the variable is declared outside. And I don't want to confuse OP by putting declaration and updating of variable in `for` loop. The code you are saying is already in the question. I just want to convey that OP should update the variable.

Comment: @DavidPineda Yes you got it right. The initial value of the variable never changes so it can never become `null` and the code go to infinite loop.